# How to click a dropdown menu and select option?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code

```
<select class="needsclick" id="country" name="order[country]">
              <option value="USA" selected="selected">USA</option>
              <option value="CANADA">CANADA</option>
            </select>
```

I could do the following javascript command to change the option value

```
document.getElementById("country").value = 'CANADA'
```

however, this does not change the selected value and does not change the state box to province.

When I physically click this dropdown menu and change to CANADA, the effects of the change take place (the state box changes to province)

I am using Swift iOS to parse HTML and wondering what line of javascript code is needed to click a option value rather than changing the option value?

If I do the following after changing the value

```
document.getElementById("country").click()
```

it just clicks the menu but still does not change the state box to province (happens when physically clicking the option value)

How can I achieve this using a javascript command like the two above?

The state/province box is irrelevant to the code just relevant to the fact it changes when the dropdown is physically clicked and not when programmatically changed.

I can do the following code but it still does not change the state box to province (only if physically clicked)

```
document.getElementById("country")[1].selected = true
```

Comment: Where is the state/province box in your markup? I only see the select element for the country. It's always helpful to post a real working example, albeit a somewhat reduced one: see [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Terry, The state/province box is irrelevant to the code just relevant to the fact it changes when the dropdown is physically clicked and not when programmatically changed.

Comment: @Shrooms Aren't you having an issue with how to change the select and trigger the change in the state/province box? seems like it's relevant to me. Also how the "state/province" box is updating based on the change of the `select` would be relevant, no? I'd like a working demo of what you're working with now.

Answer (score 2):

To work with the `option` elements within a `select`, you must access the `options` node list and then select one to work with.

Setting the value is separate from setting the `selected` flag.

```js
var countries = document.getElementById("country");
var states = document.getElementById("provincesUSA");
var territories = document.getElementById("provincesCanada");

countries.addEventListener("change", function(e) { update(e); });

function update(e){
  // show the correct sub-list based on the selected option
  var country = countries[countries.selectedIndex];

  if(country.value === "USA"){
    states.classList.remove("hidden");
    territories.classList.add("hidden");      
  } else if(country.value === "CANADA") {
    territories.classList.remove("hidden"); 
    states.classList.add("hidden");    
  } else {
    territories.classList.add("hidden"); 
    states.classList.add("hidden");     
  }
}

// To dynamically choose
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  countries.options[2].selected = "selected";  // Canada
  // Simulate the change event
  update(countries);
});
```

```css
#provincesUSA.hidden, #provincesCanada.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<select class="needsclick" id="country" name="order[country]">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Choose A Country</option>
              <option value="USA">USA</option>
              <option value="CANADA">CANADA</option>
</select>

<select id="provincesUSA" class="hidden" name="states">
              <option value="al">Alabama</option>
              <option value="ar">Arkansas</option>
</select>

<select id="provincesCanada" class="hidden" name="territories">
              <option value="on">Ontario</option>
              <option value="qu">Quebec</option>
</select>

<button>Force A Selection (click me whe CANADA is NOT selected)</button>
```

Comment: this works however a physical click is still needed to change the state box to province. This works but nothing is updated after this.

Comment: @Shrooms I have updated the example with a button that shows how to change a selection via code. While this example triggers that code with a click - you can use the code wherever you need to and a click doesn't have to trigger it.

Comment: could I do something like this; document.querySelector("needsclick").addEventListener("click", function(){
  countries.options[2].selected = "selected";  // Canada
});

Comment: @Shrooms That's exactly what I am doing in the JavaScript at the bottom.

Comment: if I try document.querySelector("needsclick").addEventListener("click", function() { document.getElementById("country").options[1].selected = "selected"; });

I get the error: VM21034:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:37

Comment: That means that `document.querySelector("needsclick")` isn't finding the element. Make sure that this code is firing AFTER the document is fully parsed. Do that by putting it at the end of the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("country").selectedIndex = 2;
```

Comment: this works but it does not bring into affect the changing of the state field to province field. If i physically click the option it changes what I said.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.