# Simulate dropdown menu selection javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-select

There is this dropdown menu on a website, which looks like:

```
<form id="birthday-form" action="#" method="get">
  <select class="month">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
  </select>
  <select class="day">
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <select class="year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Now I need to simulate a selection to this form. I use this javascript to do so:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('month')[0].value = '1'; document.getElementsByClassName('day')[0].value = '1'; document.getElementsByClassName('year')[0].value = '2005';
```

So this works in the sense that the data is entered, however, the form won't submit unless I manually click it. In other words, the form shows january, 1, 2005 selected, but acts like there was no selection. As you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6mif.png) photo, the continue button is disabled (grayed out), but becomes enabled when a mouse click is clicked on, say, the february option.

I believe my question is similar to [How to click a dropdown menu and select option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946328/how-to-click-a-dropdown-menu-and-select-option), however, it appears the original question was never answered, as nothing is approved and any code I can find does not work. So, my question: how can I select options from this form and trigger something to enable the continue button.

Thank you for the help, and please let me know if my post needs editing.

Comment: Can you share the code that enables the Continue button? I'm guessing you can trigger a `change` event on one of the select elements, but it's impossible to know without seeing how the Continue button is enabled.

Comment: @raddevon sure, could you walk me through it? Do I just go to sources-event listener breakpoints - control - change?

Comment: Did you write the code that enables the Continue button? If so, just edit your question and add that to it.

Comment: @raddevon  I did not write the code, I need to find that code on the website. Is that even possible or would that be protected?

Comment: Ah, OK. You might be able to find it, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth. I might try just triggering a change event on one of the select elements and see if that works. So, set the values the way you've already done. Then, trigger a `change` event and see if the button activates. Here's some info on [how to trigger the event](https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/trigger-an-event-11/).

Comment: alright, I'll get back to you after some trial and error ;)

Comment: Sure thing! If that works, I'll submit it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: @raddevon so I did this to trigger a change: var event = new Event('change');

// Dispatch it.
test.dispatchEvent(event); //test is the options element  And I know the event triggers because I added an event listener which picks up the change. However, nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: We're shooting in the dark without knowing what activates that Continue button. You might try triggering a `click` event instead and see if that works. I guessed it might be listening for a `change`, but it could be listening for a `click` instead. The continue button activates as soon as you click one of the select elements, right?

Comment: @raddevon  actually, I did find a workaround using your advice. Thanks for the help! If you want to submit an answer feel free, I'll accept it.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help! What did you have to do, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: @raddevon I found the code the ontrigger was referencing, and I dug around in it for a while until I realized I needed to change some classes around to allow the form to accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try triggering a `change` event on one of the select elements and see if that enables the "Continue" button. Set the values the way you've already done. Then, trigger a `change` event and see if the button activates.

Here's some info on how to trigger the event: https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/trigger-an-event-11/